# In current Chrome, does rasterization happen on the main thread?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I was first looking at [this post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/How_browsers_work#paint) from MDN where it says:

> "In the painting or rasterization phase, the browser converts each box calculated in the layout phase to actual pixels on the screen...  everything occupying the main thread, including calculating styles, along with reflow and paint"

So clearly rasterization happens on the main thread.

However I am looking at [this post](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/renderingng-architecture/) from Chrome where it defined the Paint step differently:

> "Paint: compute a display list that describes how to raster GPU texture tiles from the DOM"

According to this, the Paint step, the MDN post referred to earlier, which comes after recalculating style and layout, is not where rasterization actually happens. According to this Chrome post, it happens on viz process. It seems like it is even a completely different process.

So my question is where exactly did rasterization happen in recent Chrome versions?

Comment: it's worth pointing out to you that the viz process isn't the paint process - have you read the list of the pipeline stages for chrome? Paint is step 6, Raster is mentioned in step 9, viz is step 11 I guess (aggregate) - I think the two articles use different terminology, and the MDN page is a higher level overview compared to the step by step pipeline in Chrome.

Comment: I don't understand how you have comen to *clearly rasterization happens on the main thread* in Chrome reading the Mozilla documentation, that rather is about Firefox.

Comment: it's also demonstrable that Chrome painting is more easily effected (read, stopped) by code running on the javascript engine than Firefox

Comment: Chromium uses Skia for graphics. You should find more info here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/chromium-graphics/. This page from Chromium will answer your question: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1i1Brb5FTmjStDpnUeKBphKZOJVjZzpM_rv5Wb3TMMtU/edit#slide=id.g291e5dcaed_0_0